# C - 2D Convolution

Tags: c, matrix, convolution

I'm trying to do in C language a convolution of matrices.

I've tried something but cannot do it properly.

`N[WIDTH1][WIDTH2]` is the input matrix, `M[MASK_WIDTH1][MASK_WIDTH2]` is the kernel matrix, `P[][]` the output matrix.

First attempt:

```
void convolution_2D(int N[][WIDTH2], int M[][MASK_WIDTH2], int P[][WIDTH2]) {

// find center position of kernel (half of kernel size)
int kCenterX = MASK_WIDTH2 / 2;
int kCenterY = MASK_WIDTH1 / 2;

for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH1; ++i)              // rows
{
    for (int j = 0; j < WIDTH2; ++j)          // columns
    {
        for (int m = 0; m < MASK_WIDTH1; ++m)     // kernel rows
        {
            int mm = MASK_WIDTH1 - 1 - m;      // row index

            for (int n = 0; n < MASK_WIDTH2; ++n) // kernel columns
            {
                int nn = MASK_WIDTH2 - 1 - n;  // column index

                // index of input signal, used for checking boundary
                int ii = i + (m - kCenterY);
                int jj = j + (n - kCenterX);

                // ignore input samples which are out of bound
                if (ii >= 0 && ii < WIDTH1 && jj >= 0 && jj < WIDTH2)
                    P[i][j] += N[ii][jj] * M[mm][nn];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the boundary values are wrong, because I pick the wrong values of the M matrix. For example, for `P[0][0]` the result should be, for `N` and `P` 5x5 and `M` 3x3:

```
P[0][0] = N[0][0]*M[1][1] + N[0][1]*M[1][2] + N[1][0]*M[2][1] + N[1][1]*M[2][2];
```

The values of the kernel that I need are the lower right part; instead, that code picks the upper left part and I can't write the code to check the right values.

Comment: This code assumes all values of P are initialized to zero when the function is called.

Comment: What is the point of mm and nn? If you just use m and n, it seems like it would work.

Comment: Yes, P is initialized to 0;
I feel stupid but.... I think it works.
I'm going to check the output values and close the question. Thank you!
EDIT: It works!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The values of the kernel that I need are the lower right part; instead, that code picks the upper left part and I can't write the code to check the right values.

This is because you are flipping the mask indices when you compute `mm` and `nn`. Simply remove those lines and use `m` and `n` to index the mask:

```
if (ii >= 0 && ii < WIDTH1 && jj >= 0 && jj < WIDTH2)
    P[i][j] += N[ii][jj] * M[m][n];
```